# How to hide characters in password typing

Tags: pantheon-terminal

I don't like the *** marks when I type my password in the terminal (they reveal how many characters my password has). Is there a way to turn that off so nothing appears (like every other GNU/Linux distro out there?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the severity of a recent Sudo vulnerability ([CVE-2019-18634](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-18634)), turning this feature off is an **excellent** idea regardless of whether sudo is patched or not.

this worked great for me on 5.1 (Hara):

```
sudo mv /etc/sudoers.d/pwfeedback /etc/sudoers.d/pwfeedback.disabled
```

in the event you can't wait 15 minutes to test that it works, you can kill any remaining time using:

```
sudo -k
```

and then execute your favorite sudo command without them asterisks :)

references

1. [Mint 19.1 -- Terminals show asterisks on password. How to disable
   this feature?](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=284566)
2. [How to cancel the currently-applied remaininsudo time-out?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14948/how-to-cancel-the-currently-applied-remaining-sudo-time-out)